# How do I move array child value to parent key?

Tags: php, arrays, array-splice

I need some clarity as to what PHP function can achieve what I'm aiming for.

This is a PHP array I have:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [index] => 1
        [active] => 1
        [name] => MyName
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [index] => 2
        [active] => 1
        [name] => YourName
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [index] => 4
        [active] => 1
        [name] => TheirName
    )
}
```

I want to take the "index" value and make it a KEY of that array parent, so the array would become this:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [index] => 1
        [active] => 1
        [name] => MyName
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [index] => 2
        [active] => 1
        [name] => YourName
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [index] => 4
        [active] => 1
        [name] => TheirName
    )
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how would I do this in PHP?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you all 3 for the help. I wasn't sure whom to assign as Right answer so I just picked the one with the first votes. But you've all been very helpful with this! Thank you again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but it works (it doesn't actually move the array, it just generates a new one that corresponds to your requirements):

```
$resultArr = array();
foreach ($mainArr as $value) {
    $resultArr[$value['index']] = $value;
}
unset($mainArr); // or $mainArr = $resultArr;
```

This way you won't overwrite any existing keys in your original array.

Answer (score 7):

you can use: array_column($array, null, 'index');
is the better solution, but only work for >= 5.5 php version

Comment: Good solution, just one line!

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen for this. All of the other solutions create a new array instead of altering the existing one.

Comment: OMG!! You won't know it until you try this and see the magic. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $a =  array
 (
    0 => array
    (
        "id" => 6,
        "index" => 1,
        "active" => 1,
        "name" => "MyName"
        ),

    1 => Array
    (
        "id" => 1,
        "index" => 2,
        "active" => 1,
        "name" => "YourName"
        ),

    2 => Array
    (
        "id" => 2,
        "index" => 4,
        "active" => 1,
        "name" => "TheirName"
        )
);

 $newArray = array();
 foreach ($a as $foo) {
    $newArray[$foo['index']] = $foo;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it manually with:

```
$input  = array( /* your data */ );
$output = array();

foreach ( $input as $values ) {
  $output[ $values['index'] ] = $values;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static function normArray($key, $inputArray)
{
    $outputArray = array();
    foreach ($inputArray as $item) {
        $index = intval($item[$key]);
        $outputArray[$index] = $item;
    }
    return $outputArray;
}
```